# I'm not able to convert a JSONArray to a String in JavaScript using JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, json, cookies, stringify

So, I have this JavaScript object g.

```
            g = {
                vehicles: e.Gc,
                clicked_vehicle: g,
                site_url: x.display_config.site_image_url,
                include_option_prices: !0,
                selected_options: b.Mf()
            };
            d.lead_data = g;
```

I'm trying to get the value of g.clicked_vehicle and store it in a cookie on my browser.

```
            document.cookie = "clicked_vehicle=" + JSON.stringify(g.clicked_vehicle);
```

g.clicked_vehicle is a JSONArray, so the value for the clicked_vehicle cookie that gets stored in my browser is "[object Object]". I thought JSON.stringify would turn the JSONArray into a string, but for some reason it's not working.

When I do:

```
         document.cookie = "selected_options="+ JSON.stringify(g.selected_options);
```

it works and the string gets stored to the cookie on my browser.

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: `g = {vehicles: e.Gc, clicked_vehicle: g, ...` looks recursive

Comment: `.clicked_vehicle is a JSONArray` - no it isn't. It's either a **string** (which may be a JSON notation of an array, or not), or an **Array** - there is no such thing in javascript as a `JSONArray` - - according to the code you posted, `clicked_vehicle` is `g` - what do you  *think* `g` is? or was before you clobered it (i.e. what was g before the code you posted)

Comment: What is expected result of `clicked_vehicle: g`?

Comment: what does `console.log(g)` output if you put it **before** the code you've shown

Comment: having said all that, there is no possible way that `JSON.stringify` will result in `[object Object]` - it can end up as `"[object Object]"` - note the quotes - which suggests g is the STRING `[object Object]`

Comment: Does `console` log `Uncaught ReferenceError: g is not defined`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this line here:

```
clicked_vehicle: g
```

This line may cause issues with recursion, as mentioned by Jaromanda X, as your object is also called `g`.

If you really need to store that same set of data inside of `clicked_vehicle`, you can do it like so:

```
g = {
  vehicles: e.Gc,
  clicked_vehicle: Object.assign({}, g), // copies g instead of referencing it
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: I just tried that. Unfortunately, it's still not working.

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer Can you try a `console.log` of `g.clicked_vehicle` and see what it returns you?

Comment: When I do a console.log of g.clicked_vehicle in Chrome Developer Tools it says g is not defined.

Comment: it wont recurse - the question is, what is `g` **before** that piece of code, that's what it will be. I can't see ANY reason that JSON.stringify will output `[object Object]` - so there's something the OP isn't telling us

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer No... don't do it in Chrome Developer Tools, do it in your code, i.e. add in a `console.log(g.clicked_vehicle);`, and see what that adds to Chrome Developer Tools.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, I understood your reference to the possibility of the overriding of `g` as opposed to strict recursion. Good term to use for OP's case however, and I agree that further insight into the value of `g` is necessary. I've never seen `JSON.stringify` return `[Object object]` before - that's not even valid JSON.

Comment: my guess is it's returning `"[object Object]"` - because g was the **string** `[object Object]` - so the cause of the error is earlier in the code where `g` is assigned

Comment: when I do console.log(g), I get "Object {vehicles: undefined, clicked_vehicle: k, site_url: "//pf.dataonesoftware.com/3.1.30", include_option_prices: true, selected_options: Array(4)}"

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer What is `k`?

Comment: I did a console.log(k), and it returned this function "function k(b, f) {
            var e = this;
            e.fb = f;
            e.Qa = b.Qa;
            null == g && (g = new x.g("views/builder/report"));
            this.Uf = {
                calculateTot…"

Comment: when I did a console.log on g.clicked_vehicle, it returned "k {vehicle_id: "400889922", msrp: Object, year: 2016, make: "Acura", model: "ILX"…}"

Comment: @AlgorithmicProgrammer Hmm, this doesn't make sense then... Are you sure you are not changing g.clicked_vehicle between where you are running the `console.log(g.clicked_vehicle)`, and where you tried to do `JSON.stringify(g.clicked_vehicle)`? In any other situation, the above should definitely not return `[Object object]`.